# How should I do this query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a system set up to where a user can subscribe to other people as well as a course. So john could be following sally, but also following a course such as MATH 125. Anyway, here is how my tables are set up

```
Courses
CRN | id | course_number | subject | course_name |
--------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
users
id | email | name |
-------------------
```

---

```
user_courses (shows relationship between an user and a course)
user_id | CRN
-------------
```

---

```
followers
follower | followee | id
-------------------------
```

---

```
course_updates
id | CRN | timestamp | action | user_id
---------------------------------------
```

I would like to be able to construct a news feed from these tables that shows the users name along with course information and whether they added or dropped a course; however, I'm having difficulty doing this. All of my attempts thus far have returned null. 
Here is my current attempt

```
$this->db->query("SELECT *
                  FROM courses, user_courses, course_updates
                  WHERE courses.crn = course_updates.crn
                  AND user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn
                  AND user_courses.user_id = ? ", $vars);
```

the variable being passed in via $vars is the user id of the user currently logged in. Any help making this query? thank you.

Comment: Is your problem with mysql or php?

Comment: You want to display the user name but you don't select from the table 'users'...

Comment: maybe you should separate this query to several small and clear queries? and try to use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: mysql. and yes. I simplified the query to try to get something to work. that's why there is not selection of the users table.

Comment: I'll try left join. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user.name,
courses.* ,
if(course_updates.action IS NULL, 'No Action By User',CONCAT(user.name,' ',course_updates.action,' the ',(select course_name FROM user_courses WHERE user_courses.CRN=course_updates.CRN)))

FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_courses ON user_courses.user_id =users.id
INNER JOIN courses ON user_courses.CRN=courses.CRN
LEFT JOIN course_updates ON user_courses.user_id=users.id
```

Here you can find all user with courses and if user doing any action on any courses

if you find particulate user data so add

```
WHERE users.id=$id
```

Comment: `@user26...` If you found this answer as Use full Than Mark this as accepted answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_courses.*,courses.*,user.*,course_updates.* 
FROM 
    user_courses 
        INNER JOIN courses ON user_courses.CRN=courses.CRN
        INNER JOIN users ON user_courses.user_id =users.id
        INNER JOIN course_updates ON user_courses.CRN=course_updates.CRN
WHERE users.id=$id
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic query should work, which suggests it might be a data issue.

Using more readable join syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM courses
    INNER JOIN course_updates ON courses.crn = course_updates.crn
    INNER JOIN user_courses ON user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_courses.user_id
WHERE users.id = ?
```

Can you post some test data (or just set it up on SQL fiddle)